# Querying user profile repository ATG

Tags: repository, user-profile, atg

I have added few custom properties on top of ATG's profile. When i want to read the profile values in jsp, i am just importing ATG profile and then accessing the property as profile.name.

I am facing one scenario where i need to return profile.lastName for one type of users and profile.firstName for other type of users. This is based on say profile.userType property.

Is it possible to add the userType check in repository so that when i read profile.name it should return either firstName or lastName.

Since name is referred in many places (1000) i cannot add the user type check everywhere and display name accordingly. So if possible, we can handle this in repo.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. Simply use a RepositoryPropertyDescriptor. I hastily cobbled together a version below (not tested but should be enough to get you going):

```
import atg.repository.RepositoryItem;
import atg.repository.RepositoryItemImpl;
import atg.repository.RepositoryPropertyDescriptor;

public class AcmeRealUserName extends RepositoryPropertyDescriptor{

    @Override
    public Object getPropertyValue(RepositoryItemImpl profile, Object pValue) {


        String userType = (String) profile.getPropertyValue("userType");
        String lastName = (String) profile.getPropertyValue("lastName");
        String firstName = (String) profile.getPropertyValue("firstName");      

        if ("firstNameUser".equals(userType)) {
            return firstName;
        } else {
            return lastName;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setValue(String pAttributeName, Object pValue) {
        //Probably Do Nothing since this is a derived property
    }

    /**
     * A class specific logDebug method to output log messages. Unfortunately
     * using System.out as the mechanism.
     * 
     * @param pMessage
     */
    protected void logDebug(String pMessage) {
        System.out.println("### DEBUG(:" + getClass().getName() + getName() + ")" + pMessage);
    }
}
```

You then refer to this new property in your userprofiling.xml as follow:

```
<property name="name" property-type="com.acme.propertydescriptor.AcmeRealUserName" item-type="string" writable="false" readable="true" />
```